# Prompt User for Input but display Input on Form

Tags: javascript, html

Good Morning,

Does anyone know how to correct the code below? First, I prompt the user for the variables `first` and `second` but am failing to have them display on the form. Second, when the user clicks on the `Determine the larger number` button it is supposed to run the `if` and `else if` statement located under the `function determineLarge(){` but it fails to run. My apologies as I am learning at the university to code this language. Thank you for the help.

```
 <script>
        function determineLarge(){

        let first = prompt ("Enter the first number.");
            first= document.myForm.first.value;
    
        let second = prompt("Enter the second number.");
            second =document.myForm.first.value;

            first = parseFloat(first);
            second = parseFloat(second);

            let message = "";

            if (first <0 || second <0){
                message = "You can't use negative numbers.";
                }
            else if (first > second){
                message = "The second number" + "(" + second + ")" + " is smaller.";
                }
                else if (second > first) {
                    message = "The first number" + "(" + first + ")" + " is smaller.";
                }
                else if (first == second || second==first){
                    message = "The first number" + "(" + first + ")" + " is smaller.";
                }

        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = message;
        }        
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Gary's Smaller of Two Numbers</h1>
    <form name="myForm">
    <p> Enter the first number</p>
    <input type="number" name="first" value="" onclick="javascript:determineLarge();">
    <p>Enter the second number</p>
    <input type="number" name="second" value="" onclick="javascript:determineLarge();">
    <button type="button" onclick="determineLarge();">Determine the larger number</button>
     </form>
    <div id="results"> </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I think you mean to reverse the right and left sides of the `=` on these lines: `second =document.myForm.first.value;`. The `first` and `second` variables have already been set, so now you need to set the form input values by assigning them... by putting them on the left and assigning the `first` or `second` value from the right.

Answer (score 2):

I separated the getting of the values and processing of them into two functions.

I put the prompts in a while loop so you are forced to enter in a real value greater than zero.

Also you overwrite the first and second variables by keeping the variable name first ie: first = .... instead of document.myform.value == first etc..

```js
first = -1;
second = -1;

function getValues(){
     while(isNaN(first) || first == "" || first < 0){
        first = prompt ("Enter the first number.");
     }
     
     while(isNaN(second) || second == "" || second < 0){
        second = prompt ("Enter the second number.");
     }
     
     document.myForm.first.value = first;
     document.myForm.second.value = second;
}

function determineLarge(){
            let message = "";

            if (first > second){
                message = "The second number" + "(" + second + ")" + " is smaller.";
                }
                else if (second > first) {
                    message = "The first number" + "(" + first + ")" + " is smaller.";
                }
                else if (first == second || second==first){
                    message = "The first number" + "(" + first + ")" + " is smaller.";
                }

        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = message;
        }
```

```html
<h1>Gary's Smaller of Two Numbers</h1>
    <form name="myForm">
    <p> Enter the first number</p>
    <input type="number" name="first" value="" onclick="javascript:getValues();">
    <p>Enter the second number</p>
    <input type="number" name="second" value="" onclick="javascript:getValues();">
    <button type="button" onclick="determineLarge();">Determine the larger number</button>
     </form>
    <div id="results"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed the prompt so that the inputs can be used. No need to call onClick on the text input.

```html
<script>
  function determineLarge(myForm) {

    var first = myForm.first.value;

    var second = myForm.second.value;

    console.log(first, second)

    first = parseFloat(first);
    second = parseFloat(second);

    let message = "";

    if (first < 0 || second < 0) {
      message = "You can't use negative numbers.";
    } else if (first > second) {
      message = "The second number" + "(" + second + ")" + " is smaller.";
    } else if (second > first) {
      message = "The first number" + "(" + first + ")" + " is smaller.";
    } else if (first == second || second == first) {
      message = "The first number" + "(" + first + ")" + " is smaller.";
    }

    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = message;
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Gary's Smaller of Two Numbers</h1>
  <form name="myForm">
    <p> Enter the first number</p>
    <input type="number" name="first" value="">
    <p>Enter the second number</p>
    <input type="number" name="second" value="">
    <button type="button" onclick="determineLarge(this.form);">Determine the larger number</button>
  </form>
  <div id="results"> </div>

</body>
```